# NSwag change controller description

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

I want to change controller description of [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) UI in .Net Core. I am using latest version (13.8.1). How to achieve this?

[image]

From the image above, I want to rename the title `RefUserLocation` to `User Location`. But doesn't change the endpoint itself where users are still able to access to `api/refuserlocation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[OpenApiTag("RenameName")]` to your controller like below:

```
using NSwag.Annotations;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[OpenApiTag("User Location")]
public class RefUserLocationController : ControllerBase
{...}
```

Result:
[image]

**Note:**

I use `NSwag.AspNetCore version 13.8.2`.So the `SwaggerTag` is obsolete,if you used the older version of nswag,you could use `[SwaggerTag("User Location")]`.